# Should I update or get a new ESTA?

Tags: transit, esta, applications, application-status

I have a specific question about ESTA.

In April of 2017, I traveled from Argentina to Japan, but I made a stopover in Atlanta. So I had to get the ESTA. The thing is that at the time in the travel information, I put that traveled in "transit", but now, in a few months I will visit New York

The question is... do I have to make a new application? or update it? or I can use the one I have (it is valid until the end of December)

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Also related: [ESTA Transiting first, then entering the US](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/39698/19400) and [Using ESTA a second time - first for tourism, now for transit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/62610/19400)