# Reusing an ESTA with different travel information

Tags: usa, esta

I have valid ESTA from 1.5 years ago when I stayed in Pennsylvania. I now need to travel to the US again, but this time I only need to do so for a layover en route to Canada. When I try to update the travel details on my ESTA, I can't change my answer to the question "Is your travel to the US occurring in transit to another country?" from "no" to "yes". Do I need a new ESTA, or should I just delete all of the information under "Address while in the US"?

Comment: Sorry to have closed this unilaterally -- I didn't realize until now that I had the gold "usa" badge.  If the linked duplicate does not answer your question, please advise as to why, and I will reopen this one.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. A slightly better related answer can be found [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62610/using-esta-a-second-time-first-for-tourism-now-for-transit?rq=1)